# What fuel do battlestars use?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, propulsion

It is given that battlestars use some sort of reaction mass to move, as they have glowing blue engines in the back end, unlike the cylon basestars, which are only presumed to move using a form of reaction-less drive.

***What sort of fuel do Battlestars use as non-FTL propulsion?***

Comment: “How do you think that Battlestar propels itself?” “Looks like some kind of reaction mass.” “How can you tell?” “Well, it’s so blue and glow-y.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Tylium is a material used to fuel the propulsion systems of Colonial and Cylon spacecraft. At least three forms exist: tylium ore, refined tylium precursor, and refined tylium (the fuel itself).

according to the wiki, and i remember this from the show Tylium is the primary fuel. [wiki](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Tylium)

Comment: Thanks! It's been a while since I watched the show, and I was curious!

Comment: The article on [FTL Drive](http://galactica.wikia.com/wiki/FTL_Drive) says Tylium is the fuel for the FTL system--"On human ships, the FTL Drives are powered by refined tylium". Is there evidence it's also used for slower-than-light propulsion?

Comment: as far as i know its the same fuel for everything

Comment: But by "as far as i know" do you just mean you don't know any evidence to the contrary so you assume it is, or is there any positive evidence to support this?

Comment: @Hypnosifl as in from my remembrance of the show, this is the case, and it agrees with the wiki, but no im not 100% positive their isnt contradicting info out their.

Comment: Also, even if Tylium in some sense fuels the sublight propulsion system, there might be some ambiguity here in that the fuel might not be the same as the glowing blue propellant we could see emitted by the engines--a real-life comparison would be the [nuclear electric rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electric_rocket), where there is some nuclear fuel that powers a nuclear reactor, which supplies electrical energy to an ion drive where non-nuclear ions are the propellant that is actually shot out from the ship.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an episode in which at the time captain a dharm based on an episode in which at the time captain Lee Adama States that due to issues with tylium supplies  all pilots are to watch their fuel burn until further notice .  I believe this is season two episode five .

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your answer? It is recommended that you support your answer with as much evidence to show proof your answer is valid and not just an assumption you've made.